# Use docker swarm without docker machine

Tags: docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-machine

Is it possible to use docker swarm with docker compose only without a docker machine?

If yes, How can I realize that?

Answer (score 1):

`docker-machine` designed for create virtual docker host in your environment. if you manage your virtual machines with another tools like *VMWare ESX* you don't neet to `docker-machine`.

`docker swarm` doesn't related to `docker-machine` and you can init swarm on a single node. 
your single node is manager without any worker node.

after that you can compose your services with docker compose and deploy your stack on swarm.